# Woocommerce related <script> showing as text at bottom of browser in localhost?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, localhost, themes, e-commerce

I am fairly new to Woocommerce as well as customizing themes and I can't figure out why the  below shows up as text at the bottom of the document. I have only served the website locally thus far. I was hoping there was a simple mistake I was making that someone with more experience could clear up for me quickly.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var c = document.body.className;
    c = c.replace(/woocommerce-no-js/, 'woocommerce-js');
    document.body.className = c;
</script>
```

This script (as well as others related), also overlays the entire front-page.php and restricts access to buttons and other website functionality as well.

[Image of Issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/24b3T.png)
I haven't included any of my custom theme code. Please ask questions and I will post code as needed.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

After just about every form of testing and searching possible. I figured out that my custom CSS stylesheet was causing the issue. The code below was causing all the problems. Not sure why it was allowing the code to show up, but lesson learned. Isn't life funny like that? *Forces laugh and attempts smile but instead cries*

```
body *{ display: block; }
```